# Multipart request using retrofit failed to connect to the endpoint

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to upload a video to the server with a webAPI using retrofit 2.
[here is the link to the API](https://docs.api.video/5.1/vod-tutorial/step-3-upload-a-video-file)

the post request looks like this :

```
POST /videos/vitq4gOj8GyDT9kyxPQoyNJl/source HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.api.video
Authorization: Bearer access_token
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="source.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

and this is my API interface :

```
public interface Client {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/videos/{videoId}/source")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadVideo(@Path("videoId") String videoId,
                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
    }
```

and my actual implementation in the main activity is like this :

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //getting file and making a responce body
                        File video = new File(files.toString());
                        MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Title",video.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"),video));
                        //Inteceptor
                        OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpclient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                        okhttpclient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request request = chain.request();
                                Request newRequests = request.newBuilder().
                                        addHeader("Host","ws.api.video").
                                        addHeader("Authorization",token_type+" "+accesTesxt.getText()).
                                        addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW").
                                        build();

                                return chain.proceed(newRequests);
                            }
                        });
                        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().
                                baseUrl("https://ws.api.video").
                                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
                                client(okhttpclient.build());
                        Retrofit retrofit1 = builder.build();
                        Client client1 = retrofit1.create(Client.class);

                        Call<ResponseBody> call1 = client1.uploadVideo(getVideoId.getText().toString(),file);
                        call1.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });



                    }
                });
```

when I clicked the button that should actually upload the video file but im getting a toast message from `onFailure` method like this :

[image: Toast message by the <code>onFailure</code> method]

Can anyone point out where I'm doing the mistake

Comment: https://docs.api.video/5.1/videos/upload-a-video    This is another link from the API documentation where you can see the response body, headers.

Comment: try logging the `Throwable` that's causing the issue from `onFailure`, you should get the full error message and it should be easy understanding what's wrong

Comment: actually the Toast message is itself the ``Throwable`` message from ``onFailure`` method :  ``Failed to connect to ws.api.video/2404:c580:500:0:93:878f:8300:0:443 ``